# How to insert a new field in MongoDB table with matching _id using python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have one table (table1) in my mongodb as below. For example i have given only 2 entries but count can be in thousand....

```
table1:

_id Name Class
1  'xyz'  '12th'
2  'abc'  '11th' and so on....
```

and I have another table (DataFrame) in my notebook(python) as below

```
table2:

_id zip_code
1   123
2   121
3   145 and so on....
```

Now my requirement to update by mongodb table1 like below through python program.

```
_id Name Class   zip_code
1  'xyz'  '12th' 123
2  'abc'  '11th' 121
```

So basically i want to run my python code to insert `zip_code` col from `table2` into `table1` mongodb with matching `_id`.

Comment: You can add new field in an existing dataframe by taking it as ```dict```. Then you can iterate the dicts in a loop and assign them new fields. Then you can update the database for keeping track (this step is optional) of the new added field. Then you can print the dataframe easily

Comment: I am able to add new field in python notebook but my requirement to update db directly...